# Getting rid of newline in CString in C++

Tags: c++, xml, string, newline, cstring

I have a html/xml document that is originally a CString and I want to get rid of all the newlines, essentially put everything into one line. I've tried converting it to std::String and using:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\n'), str.end());
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: if you got a char* (c-string as I interpreted from your topic), why not move along every char and use something like this: `if(string[i] == '\n') string[i] = ' ';` not exactly how a book would describe good code (as there are probably special functions for such purpose) but it would be a working fix.

Comment: This is the CString I'm talking about: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174288.aspx

Comment: on windows the newline delimiter is not "\n" but "\r\n".

Comment: Unless you want to replace the newlines with another character (space for example) there isn't any method that does that. What you can do is loop over every character in the string, appending them to another string except if the current character is the newline, when done you have a new string containing no newlines.

Comment: It seems I might have been wrong... What about the [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4931ye.aspx) function?

Comment: What you have works: https://ideone.com/Q3KfV

Comment: try without converting FROM CString  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300579(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: @TobiasSchlegel, I converted the CString to std::string then used that erase function above, str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\r\n'), str.end());            But it still didn't work.

Comment: @loler, I tried that and it didn't work lol.

Comment: @user1564795, you will need to passes over `str`: one with `'\r'` and one with `'\n'`.

Comment: @hmjd, I don't understand what you mean, could you please explain a little further?

Comment: @user1564795: `str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\n'), str.end());` and `str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\r'), str.end());` because `'\r\n'` is a multi-byte character constant, with an implementation defined value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only to use the method remove

```
CString str = _T("Test newline \nremove"), str2;
str.Remove('\n');
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to stop your block of text looking odd, you'd want to replace the line breaks with a space. Make sure to replace both newline('\n') and carriage return('\r') characters.

```
CString str = "Line 1 Windows Style\r\n Line 2 Unix Style\n Line 3";
str.Replace('\r', " ");
str.Replace('\n', " ");
str.Replace("  ", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
str.Replace("\n", "");
```

Documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ztyt5e9c)